# Copy multiple CSV files into postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a SQL script to copy multiple .CSV files into a postgres database like this:

```
COPY product(title, department) from 'ys.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

I have multiple files I want to copy in.  I don't want:

```
COPY product(title, department) from 'ys1.csv' CSV HEADER;
COPY product(title, department) from 'ys2.csv' CSV HEADER;
COPY product(title, department) from 'ys3.csv' CSV HEADER;
COPY product(title, department) from 'ys4.csv' CSV HEADER;
COPY product(title, department) from 'ys5.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

I would like to use a for loop for this instead of multiple copy commands. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Using a `do` block maybe? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

Answer (score 17):

In linux pipe the output of the files listing to psql. Make `copy` use the standard input:

```
cat /path_to/ys*.csv | psql -c 'COPY product(title, department) from stdin CSV HEADER'
```

Look for the equivalent in other OSs

Answer (score 10):

I tried the answer above but I got an error when working with more then one file. I think on the second file it didn't cut off the header.

This worked fot me:

```
# get filenames
IMPFILES=(path/FileNamepart.csv)

# import the files
for i in ${IMPFILES[@]}
    do
        psql -U user -d database -c "\copy TABLE_NAME from '$i' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER"
        # move the imported file
        mv $i /FilePath
    done
```

In my case I move every file afer it is imported. If an error occours I know where to look. And I can run the script again if there are new files put in that location.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the `PROGRAM` (Postgres > 9.3) keyword but you have the header in each csv file you can use `awk` :

```
COPY product(title, department) FROM PROGRAM 'awk FNR-1 ys*.csv | cat' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Postgres 9.3, you can run a shell command using the `PROGRAM` keyword within the [`COPY` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).

```
COPY product(title, department) from PROGRAM 'cat ys*.csv' FORMAT CSV HEADER
```

Comment: note - this doesn't work if each file has the header in the CSV.

Comment: FORMAT throws an err for me (postgres 11). This works (and skips header): \copy test from program 'cat ~/Documents/scratch/1col_text*.csv' with (format csv, delimiter ',', header);

Comment: To use this when each CSV has a header, change PROGRAM to `'awk "NR == 1 || FNR > 1" ys*.csv`. That drops the first line from all files after the first.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the filenames using pg_ls_dir.

```
DO $$

DECLARE file_path TEXT; -- Path where your CSV files are
DECLARE fn_i TEXT; -- Variable to hold name of current CSV file being inserted
DECLARE mytable TEXT; -- Variable to hold name of table to insert data into

BEGIN

    file_path := 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/my_csvs/'; -- Declare the path to your CSV files. You probably need to put this in your PostgreSQL file path to avoid permission issues.
    mytable := 'product(title,department)'; -- Declare table to insert data into. You can give columns too since it's just going into an execute statement.

    CREATE TEMP TABLE files AS 
    SELECT file_path || pg_ls_dir AS fn -- get all of the files in the directory, prepending with file path
    FROM pg_ls_dir(file_path);

    LOOP    
        fn_i := (select fn from files limit 1); -- Pick the first file
        raise notice 'fn: %', fn_i;
        EXECUTE 'COPY ' || mytable || ' from ''' || fn_i || ''' with csv header';
        DELETE FROM files WHERE fn = fn_i; -- Delete the file just inserted from the queue
        EXIT  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM files) = 0;
     END LOOP;

END $$;
```

Comment: Permission requirements to use `pg_ls_dir` differ by pg version. Works on pg 13 on desktop but not on server.

Answer (score 2):

Just one option more, using pg_ls_dir and format(). Inserting all files from 'E:\Online_Monitoring\Processed\' folder into ONLMON_T_Online_Monitoring table.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  directory_path VARCHAR(500);
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
  directory_path := 'E:\\Online_Monitoring\\Processed\\';
    FOR rec IN SELECT pg_ls_dir(directory_path) AS file_name
    LOOP
      EXECUTE format(
            '
                COPY ONLMON_T_Online_Monitoring
                    (
                        item
                    , storeCode
                    , data
                    )
                FROM %L
                WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
                ', directory_path || rec.file_name
        );
    END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

Comment: Permission requirements to use `pg_ls_dir` differ by pg version. Works on pg 13 on desktop but not on server.

Answer (score 0):

For a process that works with a remote server or a local one, you can use:

```
export PGPASSWORD=12345;
for x in $(ls *.csv)
do
    psql -d <database> -U <username> -c "\copy <schema>.<tablename> FROM '$x' CSV HEADER"
done
```

It's subtle, but this is different from the commands above since it users the built in `\copy` command which can ship files over a server and doesn't need them available there locally.